# How to handle wrong csv separator error when i'm trying to read csv from fileInput

Tags: r, csv, error-handling, shiny

I'm trying to upload file into my shiny app. 
User should be able to choose csv file and columns separator.

But when user choosed wrong separator my app is not able to use columns from this file. And what I want is to handle this wrong separator and ask user to choose right one.

I tried some validation (check length of data vector of first line which was read) but I'm something missing in my code because it goes through validation part of code without error message:

```
observeEvent(input$button1, {
    input_file <- input$input_file
    if (is.null(input_file))
        return(NULL)
    else{
        data_stream <<- DSD_ReadCSV(input_file$datapath, header=input$file_header, sep=input$file_sep, quote=input$file_quote, loop = TRUE)

        validate(
             need(length(get_points(data_stream,1)) > 1, "Error while loading file"), 
             "Wrong file format or file separator, try again to choose file or to check separator settings!"
             ) 
    }
})
```